# Service or Alarm manager

Tags: android, adt

I am making a simple android application, in which I have to notify the user about some status like reminder a user to read some article. the user schedules for a reminder and when the reminder show the message and when he tap on it, the application opens the article. 
So, my question is that, should I use service for this purpose or alarm manager ?

Answer (score 2):

Always use the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to run your code at a given point in time. Money quote:

> The Alarm Manager is intended for cases where you want to have your application code run at a specific time, even if your application is not currently running.

Comment: Well, the user schedules the notification which in turn will invoke the activity, so it would be better to use the alarm manager rather than the service.

Answer (score 1):

Alarm manager would be lighter.
See the difference between both as follows.
Use services when you need continuous operation that runs indefinitely in the background.
Use alarms when you need to perform a certain (and short) task at some point in the future, but stay idle until then.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to android too and in the learning phase so please pardon my ignorance if I am wrong but if you want your application to run in the background continuously to check for the updates and set off an alarm when there is some update, then you will need Service as well as AlarmManager. In this case, you will need to ask yourself, whether to use AlarmManager or Handler thread. But again, in case of HAndler thread, you will have to look for WakeLock handling for keeping the handler running while the phone screen is off (CPU sleep mode). In this case AlarmManager wins as it has handled wakelocks internally. But if the repetition time is small then using Handler proves to be benefitial.

Please correct me in case I am wrong or missed something so that I too can learn something new.